# Rebuild failure when installing jupyterlab/latex extension

Tags: python, latex, jupyter-lab

When I try to install the jupyterlab/latex extension, it always fails. More precisely, the extension first does not show up and then, if I try to rebuild, an error occurs (build failed with 500) that it is not possible to rebuild. I am not completely sure if I fulfill all the requirements though:

In the documentation, the requirements are:

- Python >= 3.6 --> *I do have Python version 3.7.6*
- JupyterLab 1.0 --> *I do have version 1.2.6*
- An application that can compile .tex files to PDF (e.g., pdflatex, xelatex; use pdflatex.exe on Windows with MiKTeX). This application must be available as a command in the same environment as the notebook server. --> *I have installed MiKTeX in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9*
- An application that can process .bib files for producing bibliographies. As with the LaTeX command, this must be available in the same environment as the notebook server. --> *I am not completely sure what is meant with this requirement though*

Has anybody been faced with a similar issue and could help me out? Thanks a lot in advance!

**Edit 1**: I checked the log file and there seems to be the following problem:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'worker-loader' in 'C:\Users\eliob\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\pdfjs-dist'

**Edit 2**: I tried reinstalling some packages, my log file no says there is different problem:
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in 'C:\Users\eliob\node_modules\webpack\lib\node'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem right now. I solved it by:

1. Uninstalling the extension completely from JupyterLab
2. Rebuilding and reloading JupyterLab
3. Installing the extension from pip, as the [documentation](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-latex) says, using `pip install jupyterlab_latex`, making sure you are using pip from conda (you can check by running `which pip` con terminal). This is probably what was causing the problem for me.
4. Run `jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/latex`
5. Finally, open JupyterLab and it should work.

Even if doesn't work, you could also open a terminal in JupyterLab and compile the `.tex` from there easily doing the following: Make a `.sh` file in your folder (or in templates folder, to be able to load a copy anywhere) containing the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# get the folder's name as a variable. 
archivo=${PWD##*/} 

# runs pdflatex with minimun output (using texfot)
texfot pdflatex $archivo.tex

# if a Rnw exists, then runs it too
count=`ls -1 *.Rnw 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
if [ $count != 0 ]
then 
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('$archivo.Rnw')"
texfot pdflatex $archivo.tex
fi 

# opens evince to view the pdf.
evince $archivo.pdf
```

It assumes the `.tex` file you are trying to compile is called the same as the containing folder. This is recommended anyways. It also works for Rnoweb files using knitr for Sweaving.

With that you'll be able to work `.tex` files from JupyterLab as easily as with the extension (and even with `.Rnw` files).

Comment: This is great, it worked for me finally :) !! Thanks so much ! Very happy that I can finally use it properly .